# DNN View as Non-Admin

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

With a DNN site where the user's credentials are set based on their AD login, if that user is an Admin or Host user, is there a way for the user to choose to see the site without all the Admin/Host functionality? I.e., is there a simple way to allow the user to switch the mode they're viewing the site it to remove the Host/Admin bar at the top, as well as the icons and update features around the content?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a feature built into DNN. If you're logged in with Admin/Host or even Edit permissions, you'll see the Control panel.

If you're on DNN7 you won't see the "icons" for most modules (unless the modules are hard coded that way) unless you are in EDIT Mode.